# Search and move

Tags: c#, winforms

I set up a search function to search my rich text box. It will go through the text box and highlight all the different cases that match. the rich text box lists a name then goes to the next line so what I want to do is to export not just the highlighted stuff but the whole name to a different text box. This is what I have so far for a search function.

```
      private void Search_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;
        string temp = Display_Rich_Text_Box.Text;
        //bool k;
        Display_Rich_Text_Box.Text = "";
        Display_Rich_Text_Box.Text = temp;
        string[] fullName;

        while (index <= Display_Rich_Text_Box.Text.LastIndexOf(Search_Text_Box.Text))
        {
            //Searches and locates the text you are searching for
            Display_Rich_Text_Box.Find(Search_Text_Box.Text, index, Display_Rich_Text_Box.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

            //Color Selection: Hightlights in yellow
            Display_Rich_Text_Box.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
            count = count + 1;

             fullName =  Display_Rich_Text_Box.split("\n")

            //Will search through rest of document or until it cannot continue
            index = Display_Rich_Text_Box.Text.IndexOf(Search_Text_Box.Text, index) + 1;
        }

        // if (count > 0)
        //{
        Form2 f = new Form2(count.ToString(), fullName.tostring());
        f.ShowDialog();
        }
```

(the text box is on a different form and this form also displays how many matches are found (count)).

So I tried splitting the text box when it breaks for a new line after it highlights the text.

ex:   Search for fold (typed in Search_Text_Box)

folder A
folder B
new design
pictures

So when it searches it highlights whats typed in Search_Text_Box. what I am trying to do is split the string responsible for the Display_Text_Box so it will display folder A and folder B in a separate text box if the user types fold. The text box is in a different form. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What do you  mean by "the whole name"? is this searching names in a rich text box?

Comment: The program finds folder and file names and displays them in the rich text box. Each name gets its own line. Ex: folder1 (new line), folder2 (new line)... So if I type fol in the search box and execute the search. it will highlight fol; however, I would like to export fol and the rest of the line so it should move folder2 to a new textbox as well. Does that help?

Comment: Would it help if you split the input up by `\n`?

Comment: /*Ex: of input


    folder A \n
    folder B \n
    new folder \n
    project 1 \n

    Goes on for awhile. The search function so far will highlight searched material.
    So if fo is searched it highlights fo in folder A, B and in new folder. What i would like to 
    do is output any name that contains the highlighted parts so the user doesnt have to 
    put in the full title to look at different cases containing similar words. I thought
    about trying to follow it back to the last new line to get the name, but so far it is not working right*/

Comment: I didn't answer that well. They are separated  by a new line

Comment: You're missing what I'm saying. I'm saying you can do `Display_Rich_Text_Box.Text.Split('\n')` and iterate through the list.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. I think I understand what your idea is which is to make it go to the end of the line it highlighted by using text.split, but I guess I am not following the rest.

Comment: It would make sense to use split('\n') if I could isolate the index number to go above and below it without affecting the rest of the string

Comment: Updated my answer, I'm doing a lot of blind coding and have no clue what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: If you have more information, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38307838/edit) your question to include it; people often don't read comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your function to split the lines:

```
    private void Search_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lines = Display_Rich_Text_Box.Text.Split('\n');
        var count = 0;

        // To get the text from the whole line (Which is the whole name you're looking for)
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // If the line doesn't have the text you're looking for
            if (!line.Contains(Search_Text_Box.Text)) continue;

            count++;

            // Add the index of the whole input plus the index of the text within the line
            var index = lines.IndexOf(line) + line.IndexOf(Search_Text_Box.Text);

            //Searches and locates the text you are searching for
            Display_Rich_Text_Box.Find(Search_Text_Box.Text, index,
                Display_Rich_Text_Box.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

            //Color Selection: Hightlights in yellow
            Display_Rich_Text_Box.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;

            //DO SOMETHING WITH LINE
            var wholeName = line;
        }

        Form2 f = new Form2(searchCount);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: what library is Regex from? it is not showing up as a known keyword

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: @Tasha If you could mark it as the answer, I'd appreciate the rep!

Comment: I did mark it already, since I have less than 15 rep points, it was recorded but not displayed sorry.